# Scaling an iframe on Mobile Safari is breaking the iframe's links

Tags: ios, css, iframe, safari

I'm having a problem with using CCS3 transforms on an iframe in Mobile Safari. If I use `-webkit-transform: scale();` on an iframe, the contents of the iframe scale accordingly, but links in the iframe break.

Tapping the element highlights the **hitbox**, and it appears that the link **hitboxes** are not being scaled. When you tap a link, you can see the hitbox appear where the link would have been if the iframe weren't being scaled.

This gets worse the further the link is from the top left corner, regardless of where you set the transform origin.

The same page I am testing this with works perfectly on Safari and Chrome on my computer, so I suspect this is a Mobile Safari bug.

Is this a known problem? Does anybody know of a workaround? I tried using the zoom property but that only resizes the iframe, not its contents.

I've uploaded an example here: http://trrrm.com/iframe/ If you open that on an iOS device and click the links in the iframe you'll see what I mean.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175464/webpage-on-mobile-safari-is-not-scaling-to-fit-viewport

Comment: Hi terrarum
Did you ever find an answer for this? I got the exact same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Carol and Claes, I only just saw them, I guess I didn't have email notifications set up or something! I can't remember what we did in the end, but I guess Claes probably doesn't care by now either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known problem. Touch events on a scaled iframe will not work right on iOS. If you are creating the content of the iFrame, you can scale the content body element instead.

Note that even animated translations cause problems on an iOS6 - I had to force a relayout by changing the iframe's top by 1px after the animation finished to get touch events working correctly.

Webkit has [an open bug on transformed iframes](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15676).