# Webpage on mobile safari is not scaling to fit viewport?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari, viewport

I created a simple using only ems and percentages as css units. It is a container div wrapping some elements and it's center in the page with the following code:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -25.875em;
margin-left: -38.187em;
padding: 0;
width: 76.375em;
height: 47.75em;
```

It works great in all browsers except for the iphone and ipad. It renders only the top right corner of my page.

I added :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=.2, initial-scale=.6">
```

And it scaled itself down on the ipad but was still to large for the iphone and the page would not scale at all in portrait mode.

Finally by googling and playing around with the meta tag the best solution I could come up with was reducing the meta tag to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes" >
```

In combination with this :

```
@media all and ( max-device-width: 780px ) {
  body {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .page-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

The page still renders a very large scale but can be scaled down at least.

Isn't mobile safari supposed to scale the page down automatically? Are the relative units messing me up here?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: As stated above that doesn't work. All I see is the top right corner of the page and worse than that I can't scale the page in portrait mode.

Comment: Now that you've fixed the formatting, I'd guess `width: 76.375em;` is a problem, for one. Why are you setting that sort of bizarrely specific width? If you want the thing to scale for mobile, you need to stop setting fixed widths on stuff. Start simple, maybe with one of the frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap, and get a handle on things that way.

Comment: From my understanding this is a fairly common practice for creating a fluid grid layout. As outlined in this post for one example : http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/ I guess I will experiment with this further. Twitter Bootstrap css uses equally specific widths example : '.row-fluid .span11 { width: 91.48936170212765%; }' from a base size of 940px. My understanding is that I am effectively setting my container to 1222px from the base font size of 16px. I will experiment with changing that value. Thanks

Comment: You've drastically misread that article, though. Most importantly, their container div has `max-width`, not `width` set, and it's definitely not absolute positioned. Start with their base code at http://www.alistapart.com/d/fluidgrids/examples/grid/final.html and work from there... although I'd note that this fluid grid isn't going to look great on a narrow smartphone. Try responsive design with media queries for that.

Comment: I don't believe you are thoroughly reading what I'm saying here. Nor have you answered any of the questions I have asked. I can use media queries to come to a solution which I have. I'm not recreating the layout in the article. Maybe I didn't explain my layout well enough in the question but it's clear from the css that it is a box vertically and horizontally centered. I want to understand why the content is not scaling down on the iphone despite the meta tag. Can you answer that question?

Comment: You've set an explicit width on the container div. It won't scale any smaller than that width (certainly not to the 320px of an iPhone). Use a sensible HTML structure and it'll scale just fine.

Comment: Why doesn't it scale down like apple.com or udacity.com or other sites do which all have explicit widths?

Comment: Apple's viewport sets it to the exact fixed width of the design - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />`. Udacity.com doesn't set any viewport, which means iOS guesses at the right default viewport. You really should go read the docs for the tag: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html